# Merge lines based on attribute values and sequence

Tags: algorithm

Based on the input below, I want to merge the lines with same attrA value. The merge rule must follow the sequence of attrB values.

Any ideas on a simple algorithm model to solve this?

```
Input:
attrA;attrB;attrC
15;1;-20  <-- (1) merge this attrC value
15;1;-21  <--        (2) merge this attrC value
15;2;-30  <-- (1) with this attrC value
15;2;-33  <--        (2) with this attrC value
15;2;-31  <-- discarded
10;1;-24  <-- (3) merge this attrC value
10;2;-32  <-- (3) with this attrC value

Output:
(-20,-30);15     <--  (1)
(-21;-33);15     <--  (2)
(-24;-32);10     <--  (3)
```

Another input/output sample:

```
Input:
15;1;-24
15;1;-21
15;1;-23
15;2;-30
10;1;-27

Output:
(-24,-30);15
```

Edit: this is my try. I am looking for a more optimized version.

```
output = []
foreach distinct attrA in input
    inputFromAttrA = filter(input, attrA)  // get only records of current attrA value
    r = getRecordCountOfAttrB_thatHasLessRecords(inputFromAttrA)
    for i=0 to r; i++
        k = 0
        attrCmerge = []
        foreach distinct attrB in inputFromAttrA
            inputFromAttrA_and_AttrB = filter(inputFromAttrA, attrB)
            attrCmerge[k] = inputFromAttrA_and_AttrB[i]
            k++
    output[] = attrCmerge;attrA
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? What are you trying to do? Try to put your thoughts into words as a starting point.

Comment: I've added my version